# How to exclude the week of the month that has more days in the next month

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two dates. One is for the StartDate and the other is for EndDate. With this two I  want to exclude the week that has more days into the next month.

[image]

Here I have the w52 which is in 2022 and w5 which is in 2023, each of them have few days in the current month (Jan), and for this I want to exclude the w52 and w5 if the days are fewer in the current month.

Or to have something like this [Overview of dates with a fixed week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month)
, generated for each years and plus another column that indicates the month. Eg.

[image]

Comment: Hi - please don't use images, use editable text (so that someone can copy your data if they want to try a solution). Also, as you need to show at least some effort to solve this for yourself, please update your question with the SQL you have managed to write and explain exactly what the issue is that you are stuck on

Comment: Hint: 1) Get the first day of the month from the end date using DATE_TRUNC 2) Subtract this from the end date to get the number of days 3) if the number of days is between 4 and 6 (the majority, but not all, in the current month) then exclude the week

Answer (score 0):

If you write a query based on @NickW's explanation, it looks like below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT DATE '2022-12-26' DateDimStartDate, DATE '2023-01-01' DateDimEndDate UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-02', '2023-01-08' UNION ALL
  -- ...
  SELECT '2023-01-23', '2023-01-29' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-30', '2023-02-05'
)
-- query starts here
SELECT *,
       IF (
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DateDimStartDate) <> EXTRACT (MONTH FROM DateDimEndDate) AND
         LAST_DAY(DateDimStartDate) - DateDimStartDate >= INTERVAL 3 DAY,
         FORMAT_DATE('%y%m01',DateDimStartDate),
         FORMAT_DATE('%y%m01',DateDimEndDate)
       ) AS Month
  FROM sample_table;

-- query result
+------------------+----------------+--------+
| DateDimStartDate | DateDimEndDate | Month  |
+------------------+----------------+--------+
| 2022-12-26       | 2023-01-01     | 221201 |
| 2023-01-02       | 2023-01-08     | 230101 |
| 2023-01-23       | 2023-01-29     | 230101 |
| 2023-01-30       | 2023-02-05     | 230201 |
+------------------+----------------+--------+
```